# Sorting an array of dictionaries based on dictionary keys

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, nssortdescriptor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sorting NSDictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256966/sorting-nsdictionary)

Can we sort an array of dictionaries the way we do for array of arrays using NSComparator & NSSortDescriptor based on some keys in the dictionaries?