# Objective c date sorting

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, sorting

I am developing a iphone application. I want to sort the following dates. also I use a marker with dates. Markers are important for me Because I use for other a process. Please help me

```
NSMutableDictionary *myDate=[NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[myDate setObject:@"00" forKey:@"2011-08-02"];
[myDate setObject:@"01" forKey:@"2011-07-09"];
[myDate setObject:@"KUP" forKey:@"2011-06-07"];
```

Comment: @middaparka, I editted to my question

Comment: Why would you store dates as strings and not NSDates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to sort date covert them in YYYYMMDD and sort them as integer
You can convert them by using NSDateFormat

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

NSDictionaries are not sortable directly, but this answer should help: [Sorting NSDictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256966/sorting-nsdictionary)