# NSDictionary Sorting keys by default

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am working on API integration, From API I am getting the response in dictionary format, While I serialise that data, it is sorting automatically

Here is my code

```
id resposeJSon = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&err];
```

While I try to print the same in NSString it works as the response is received

```
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:adata encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

I am expecting the serialised variable resposeJSon should be in the same format what I get from variable jsonString

Thanks in advance

Comment: Order is never guaranteed in `NSDictionary` if that's what you're wondering.

Comment: Are you want serialised JSON response in NSDictionary formate or NSString...Which formate you want

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting NSDictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256966/sorting-nsdictionary)

Comment: @HunaidHassan any possibility to achieve it

Comment: Why do you need it to be in a specific order?

Comment: show us some sample json data